# get Timestamp data from oracle database in C

Tags: c, database, oracle, data-structures

I have a Table in an oracle database that has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ticket

    (
        log_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        evnt_tmstmp TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (log_id)
    );
```

to get the value from the database using unix i have to create a struct like:

```
struct link_info 
{ 
    long log_id;
    // i dont know how to store the timestamp value
};
```

I dont know what data type to store the timestamp value. THanks

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/

Comment: when I do EXEC SQL FETCH scada_cursor INTO :scada_event_ptr; it gives me an error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP.....

Answer (score 0):

excerpt from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/

> type  time_t Time type Alias of a fundamental arithmetic type
>   capable of representing times, as those returned by function time.
>
> For historical reasons, it is generally implemented as an integral
>   value representing the number of seconds elapsed since 00:00 hours,
>   Jan 1, 1970 UTC (i.e., a unix timestamp). Although libraries may
>   implement this type using alternative time representations.
>
> Portable programs should not use values of this type directly, but
>   always rely on calls to elements of the standard library to translate
>   them to portable types.

Just use time_t

Comment: when I do EXEC SQL FETCH scada_cursor INTO :scada_event_ptr; it gives me an error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP.....

Comment: if time_t compiled but got runtme error I dont know the answer sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct link_info 
{ 
    long log_id;
    time_t time;
};
```

Be sure to use the ANSI C standard functions to convert the non-portable `time_t` into a `struct tm`, which contains the components of the time.

Comment: Could you expand on converting the non-portable time_t into a struct tm?